# does rclone 'sync' work with google drive to remove files?

Tags: synchronization, google, rclone

I am trying to use rclone to sync a directory to my google drive.

The code I am using is something like:

```
rclone sync ~/Desktop/myfolder  mygoogledrive:myfolder
```

This works to upload the contents just fine. But when I remove a file from my local "myfolder" the corresponding file in Google Drive stays undeleted when I run the sync command.

So clearly I expect the file to be deleted by rclone, but should I?

Is this a supported feature for Google Drive? If so, does anyone have any thoughts on why it's not working. Am I missing a flag?